# CM9 shuts off itself on SGS2?

Tags: cyanogenmod, shutdown

I'm facing a very weird problem on my SGS2, using CM9 9.1.0 stable making me crazy. My device go to in deep sleep in 12-24 hrs once when I'm using Siyah kernel while CM9 stock kernel do it  once or twice in a day. :'(

I have Googled for it and got this thread where the problem is same. [Cm9 Phone Shuts Off By Itself](http://forum.cyanogenmod.org/topic/57122-cm9-phone-shuts-off-by-itself/), phone actually doesn't switch off it just go to in deep sleep and start to eat battery like a crazy nut, also I can call on my ohone and caller can hear up the ring but there is no life sighn at that moment in my phone.

How can I resolve this, I have did a clean install but no success, also battery of my phone is just new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I have got a workaround but not a permanent fix for this problem.

I did a clean re-install and then don't restore any backed up data through **Go Backup/Titanium Backup** app. Then I don't get that suspicious shutdown every time in a day, but after 2-3 days yes you will. :(